# How to stop equation to disappear?

Tags: equations, subequations

[image: I am writing a two-column report. I wrote an equation that is long and there are several lines. I used multlined package to fit the equation in one column. But when I compile the document, the equation is not there in full. You can see there are only 4 lines of the equation. the last line went to the very bottom of the page and the rest lines disappeared.]

I am writing a two-column report. I wrote an equation that is long and there are several lines. I used `multlined` package to fit the equation in one column. But when I compile the document, the equation is not there in full. You can see there are only 4 lines of the equation. the last line went to the very bottom of the page and the rest lines disappeared.

My code:

```
\documentclass{doublecol-new}
\usepackage{natbib,stfloats}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}



    \begin{equation}
    \begin{multlined}
          \frac{\partial L(x, z)}{\partial W_{n i}^{(2)}}=-\frac{1}{m} \sum_{b=1}^{m} \sum_{n=1}^{d} \frac{x_{b n}-z_{b n}}{z_{b n}\left(1-z_{b n}\right)} s\left(V_{j}^{(3)}\right)\\ \left(1-s\left(V_{j}^{(3)}\right)\right) 
    W_{i j}^{(3)} s\left(V_{i}^{(2)}\right)\left(1-s\left(V_{i}^{(2)}\right)\right) x_{b n}\\ 
    =-\frac{1}{m} \sum_{b=1}^{m} \sum_{n=1}^{d} \frac{x_{b n}-z_{b n}}{z_{b n}\left(1-z_{b n}\right)} A_{j}^{(3)}\left(1-A_{j}^{(3)}\right)\\ W_{i j}^{(3)} A_{i}^{(2)}\left(1-A_{i}^{(2)}\right) x_{b n}\\
    \frac{\partial L(x, z)}{\partial b_{i}^{(2)}}=-\frac{1}{m} \sum_{b=1}^{m} \sum_{n=1}^{d} \frac{x_{b n}-z_{b n}}{z_{b n}\left(1-z_{b n}\right)} s\left(V_{j}^{(3)}\right)\\ \left(1-s\left(V_{j}^{(3)}\right)\right) 
    W_{i j}^{(3)} s\left(V_{i}^{(2)}\right)\left(1-s\left(V_{i}^{(2)}\right)\right)\\
    =-\frac{1}{m} \sum_{b=1}^{m} \sum_{n=1}^{d} \frac{x_{b n}-z_{b n}}{z_{b n}\left(1-z_{b n}\right)} A_{j}^{(3)}\left(1-A_{j}^{(3)}\right)\\
     W_{i j}^{(3)} A_{i}^{(2)}\left(1-A_{i}^{(2)}\right)\\ 
     \frac{\partial L(x, z)}{\partial b_{j}^{(3)}}=-\frac{1}{m} \sum_{b=1}^{m} \sum_{n=1}^{d} \frac{x_{b n}-z_{b n}}{z_{b n}\left(1-z_{b n}\right)} s\left(V_{j}^{(3)}\right)\\
    \left(1-s\left(V_{j}^{(3)}\right)\right) 
    =-\frac{1}{m} \sum_{b=1}^{m} \sum_{n=1}^{d} \frac{x_{b n}-z_{b n}}{z_{b n}\\\left(1-z_{b n}\right)} A_{j}^{(3)}\left(1-A_{j}^{(3)}\right)
    \end{multlined}
    \end{equation}
```

Comment: Please provide a *complete* example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that shows your problem. Without knowing the document class, the loaded packages and the other settings, it is difficult to give sound advice.

Comment: Did you try adding `\allowdisplaybreaks`?

Comment: @Bernard, I did not. I will try and let you know.

Comment: Don't forget to load amsmath if it isn't already.

Comment: Is the `doublecol-new` document class available online somewhere?

Comment: @Bernard - The OP uses a single `equaition` environment -- and the contents of  `equation` environments cannot be broken across columns or pages.

Comment: @Mico: I thought it worked  for an equation with a multiline  environment nested iin it. Ive learnt something! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code provides a single `equation` environment, and `equation` environments can never be split across columns (or pages).

What you call an equation would actually appear to be 3 separate equations. I would therefore like to suggest that you embed 3 separate `multlined` environments inside a single `gather` environment -- and run `\allowdisplaybreaks` in order to allow column breaks at the ends of the `multlined` environments.

The parentheses generated by `\left(` and `\right)` would appear much too large. I suggest using `\bigl(` and `\bigr)` instead.

The following test document places the first two equations at the bottom of the left-hand column and the third equation at the top of the right-hand column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} 
    % I don't have access to 'doublecol-new' document class
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'gather' and 'multlined' environments
\allowdisplaybreaks

\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\begin{document}
\raggedbottom

\lipsum[2-3]
\begin{gather}
\begin{multlined} % start of 1st equation
\frac{\partial L(x, z)}{\partial W_{n i}^{(2)}}
    =-\frac{1}{m} \sum_{b=1}^{m} \sum_{n=1}^{d} 
    \frac{x_{b n}-z_{b n}}{z_{b n}(1-z_{b n})} 
    s\bigl(V_{j}^{(3)}\bigr)\\
    \bigl(1-s\bigl(V_{j}^{(3)}\bigr)\bigr)
    W_{i j}^{(3)} s\bigl(V_{i}^{(2)}\bigr)
    \bigl(1-s\bigl(V_{i}^{(2)}\bigr)\bigr) x_{b n}\\
    =-\frac{1}{m} \sum_{b=1}^{m} \sum_{n=1}^{d}
    \frac{x_{b n}-z_{b n}}{z_{b n}(1-z_{b n})} A_{j}^{(3)}
    \bigl(1-A_{j}^{(3)}\bigr)\\
    W_{i j}^{(3)} A_{i}^{(2)}\bigl(1-A_{i}^{(2)}\bigr) x_{b n}
\end{multlined}\\[\jot]
\begin{multlined} % start of 2nd equation
\frac{\partial L(x, z)}{\partial b_{i}^{(2)}}
    =-\frac{1}{m} \sum_{b=1}^{m} \sum_{n=1}^{d}
    \frac{x_{b n}-z_{b n}}{z_{b n}(1-z_{b n})}
    s\bigl(V_{j}^{(3)}\bigr)\\ 
    \bigl(1-s\bigl(V_{j}^{(3)}\bigr)\bigr)
    W_{i j}^{(3)} s
    \bigl(V_{i}^{(2)}\bigr)
    \bigl(1-s\bigl(V_{i}^{(2)}\bigr)\bigr)\\
    =-\frac{1}{m} \sum_{b=1}^{m} \sum_{n=1}^{d}
    \frac{x_{b n}-z_{b n}}{z_{b n}(1-z_{b n})} 
    A_{j}^{(3)}\bigl(1-A_{j}^{(3)}\bigr)\\
    W_{i j}^{(3)} A_{i}^{(2)}\bigl(1-A_{i}^{(2)}\bigr)
\end{multlined}\\[\jot]
\begin{multlined} % start of 3rd equation
\frac{\partial L(x, z)}{\partial b_{j}^{(3)}}
    =-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{b=1}^{m} \sum_{n=1}^{d}
    \frac{x_{b n}-z_{b n}}{z_{b n}(1-z_{b n})}
    \shoveleft{s\bigl(V_{j}^{(3)}\bigr)}\\
    \bigl(1-s\bigl(V_{j}^{(3)}\bigr)\bigr)\\
    =-\frac{1}{m} \sum_{b=1}^{m} \sum_{n=1}^{d}
    \frac{x_{b n}-z_{b n}}{z_{b n}}%\\
    (1-z_{b n}) A_{j}^{(3)}\bigl(1-A_{j}^{(3)}\bigr)
\end{multlined}
\end{gather}
\lipsum[4-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The second line of each equation is starting from exactly below the `=` (equal sign) of the first line. In your's output, it is starting from left. how to do that?

Comment: @NasimulHasan - I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "how to do that?" What are you referring to? Please elaborate.

Comment: The second line of each equation is starting from the middle in my case unlike yours. The image you attached shows the second line of each equation is left-aligned. I want to align the second (and next lines) line left. 

You can see this image to get a clear idea of what I am asking about.
https://imgur.com/WHk1Ga9

Comment: @NasimulHasan - The code I provided does left-align the second lines in equation. If your code doesn't do that, then you must be doing something that differs materially from the code I provided. Sadly (but probably not surprisingly), my mind-reading skills are worthless. Unless you state more clearly that it is that you are actually doing (as opposed to saying what you *want* to do), chances that I will be able to help you are infinitesimal at best.